# When does Cassandra fetches full rows when a client sends a update query

Tags: java, cassandra, nosql, datastax, cql

Lets take an example table:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    phone text
);
```

And a clients sends a update query like: `update student set name='name_temp' where id in (1, 2);`

My question is what gets saved into memtable, does it save the whole row for ids 1 and 2 (which means it has to fetch the whole row first) with updated value for `name` column or just the delta? When does the whole row gets fetched as I assume when it writes to SSTable it has to write the whole row with the latest 'name` column value.

**EDIT:**

For complete understanding please read the comments as part of the selected answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cassandra, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements are all inserts under the hood. Cassandra doesn't do a read-before-write (with the exception of lightweight transactions) so your query:

```
UPDATE student SET name='name_temp' WHERE id IN (1, 2);
```

does not "fetch the rows" before updating the 2 partitions.

All it does is insert 2 new records to the `student` table where only the `name` column is set -- for these 2 particular mutations, there is no value for the column `phone`.

Provided there are no new mutations (inserts/updates/deletes) to those 2 records, the following records get flushed from the memtable to disk:

```
{ id = 1, name = 'name_temp' }
{ id = 2, name = 'name_temp' }
```

Cassandra has sparse storage meaning only the columns with values set are stored on disk. Since the mutation did not contain the `phone` column, it will not get included in the new SSTable that resulted from the memtable flush. Cheers!

Comment: "Cassandra has sparse storage meaning only the columns with values set are stored on disk. Since the mutation did not contain the phone column, it will not get included in the new SSTable that resulted from the memtable flush." - which means many SSTables can have partial data for the same row then does that mean in the read path to get all the columns for a row Cassandra has to read all the SSTable files which contain the row, merge and return to client?

Comment: That's correct, yes. At some point, the partition fragments will coalesce into an SSTable when they get compacted together. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Update is also a write in Cassandra. So as you update those two partitions are written into memtable first and then flushed into a new sstable.

Only updated value is wriiten to memtable. Complete row is not fetched. So cells which are updated gets written.

Cassandra resolves different writes (old data and updated data) during read path. With each cell Cassandra stores a metadata for write time which is used to determine the latest data (Last Write Wins).

The different data for same partition are compacted by the process of compaction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but you did not answer my question "what gets saved into memtable, does it save the whole row for ids 1 and 2 (which means it has to fetch the whole row first) with updated value for name column or just the delta? "

Comment: Nothing is fetched from database during update, whatever cell is updated are written in memtable. Edited the answer.

Comment: if the delta/new col value is getting written to memtable, then does Cassandra write the whole row when it writes the memtable to SSTable or again just the delta?

Comment: Only delta is written. Cassandra fetches whole row during read by going across each sstable and combining the results. During write only delta will be written

Answer (score 0):

@rafel, the short answer to your question is only the columns which have been changed are updated.

Here's a good resource about the write path: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlWriteUpdate.html

This note is at the bottom of the page:

*Note:* Some database operations may only write partial updates of a row, so some versions of a row may include some columns, but not all. During a compaction or write, Cassandra assembles a complete version of each row from the partial updates, using the most recent version of each column.

Comment: Is that true for version 2.2 as I don't see the same *note* for 2.2 https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/2.2/cassandra/dml/dmlWriteUpdate.html